# Wildfly deployment failed

Tags: java, wildfly

I've tried to deploy my application using Wildfly Management Console (wildfly 10.1.0.Final) but unfortunately failed due to the following reason / error :

Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit."MTCSE_App.ear"."MTCSE_EJBApp.jar".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."MTCSE_App.ear"."MTCSE_EJBApp.jar".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "MTCSE_EJBApp.jar" of deployment "MTCSE_App.ear" Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit."MTCSE_App.ear"."MTCSE_EJBApp.jar".PARSE"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined

I'm trying to deploy a ear file and it is throwing me the above error. Can you provide the possible reasons and solutions to the error.